# android- login control

Tags: android, authentication, formview

I am building a simple checkout process on the phone and was wondering if there are prebuilt controls that are available in android apk:

1. Login Control: username, password, login button
2. Form View where the user can just submit all the info.
3. Some sort of the "More info" control that has a collapsed/expanded view for product description
4. Tabs control: something like iPhone music player tabs.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such thing in standard android library. I don't know about 3rd party stuff - internet is wast, you might find something.

There is the `API Demos` app in your android SDK. It shows all standard widgets provided in android. I believe [AlertDialogSample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlertDialogSamples.html) is what you might be looking for.

There are also [other demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=sample) showing how to use most (all?) functionality in android.